# What is the meaning of a negative Standardized mean difference (SMD)?

Tags: propensity-scores, standardized-mean-difference

The core of my question is: What is the meaning of a negative SMD?

To assess the balance after Propensity Score Matching (PSM) with the R package `MatchIt` the [documentation explains](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/MatchIt.html) the `Std. Mean Diff` (Standardized mean difference).

The values in that example are positive and negativ. My **problem** is that there are also negative.

Because [Linden (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1111/jep.12072) explained that the SMD could have cut-offs from `0.10` to `0.25`. This means a value higher then `0.10` (or `0.25`; where ever you set your cut off) means imbalance.
But Linden never wrote about negativ values.

This is the formula Linden used in the publication:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standardized mean differences are not always presented in absolute value. In `MatchIt`, they are not. A negative SMD just means the control group has a larger mean the the treated group, and a positive SMD just means the treated group has a larger mean than the control group. The cutoffs refer to the absolute value of the SMD, but an SMD of -.15 has the same degree of imbalance as an SMD of .15.